# I need following table in LateX code including special symbols

Tags: tables, amsmath, texstudio, relation-symbols, semantics

I hope you can you help me. I am writing my homework with LaTeX (using TexStudio as environment).

[image]

This table contains three columns: Syntax, Strictness and Semantics. For my homework, I need to describe these table and the most important thing is the Semantics column. The developers used special algebraic symbols which I cannot find in the math package. Take for example the first line. The variable "i" underneath the "x" means that "i" will replace "x". But the fraction symbol is not really a fraction, isn't it? How can I use this in LaTeX? If you go futher until the "while" condition, you will realize the long dashed line, how can I use this?

It will be my first table in LaTeX because I have not used LaTeX for writing my essays/projects. I need also to know how tables are generated using LaTeX.

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx!  If you do not know nothing about LaTeX tables you should start with that question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really a beginner's task. Anyway, I think that this is a good occasion for learning something about LaTeX.

1. Define commands for the various subtasks, after deciding what are the more frequent constructions and dividing them by kind;
2. look at the table layout: we recognize three columns (r, c and l) in the “Original language syntax” part;
3. add the items in a consistent way.

The structure I recognize are “metavariables”, “keys” (subdivided into words, operators, binary operations, relations and punctuation). In the last column, we can see the constructs in angle brackets; the fraction-like objects have been dealt with an `array`, with solid or dotted separator.

Finally, for the few cases a line has to be broken up, I define an *ad hoc* `\dbl` command. In a couple of cases, manual intervention is necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb,array,arydshln}

\newcommand{\meta}[1]{\mathit{#1}}
\newcommand{\kword}[1]{\mathtt{#1}}
\newcommand{\kop}[1]{\mathop{{}\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\kbin}[1]{\mathbin{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\krel}[1]{\mathrel{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\kpun}[1]{\mathpunct{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\str}[1]{[\textit{#1}]}
\newcommand{\sem}[2]{\langle #1\rangle_{\mathsf{#2}}}
\newcommand{\sop}[2]{#1_{\mathit{#2}}}
\newcommand{\Ceq}{\Coloneqq}
\newcommand{\dbl}[1]{\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{array}}
\newcommand{\subexp}[2]{\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\newcommand{\sv}{\subexp{\mbox{\enspace}}{\mbox{\enspace}}}
\newcommand{\dsubexp}[2]{%
  \begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\\\cdashline{1-1}[.4pt/1pt]#2\end{array}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{
  |
  >{$}r<{$}
  @{}
  >{${}}c<{{}$}
  @{}
  >{$}l<{$}
  |
  l
  |
  >{$}l<{$}
  |
}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Original language syntax} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Strictness} &
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{Semantics} \\
\hline
\meta{AExp}
& \Ceq & \meta{Int}\mid \meta{Id} &
&
\sem{\subexp{x}{i}\quad \sv}{k} \quad \sem{\sv\quad x\mapsto i\quad \sv}{state} \\
& \mid & \meta{AExp}\kbin{+}\meta{AExp} &
\str{strict} &
i_1\kbin{+}i_2 \to i_1 \sop{+}{Int} i_2 \\
& \mid & \meta{AExp}\kbin{/}\meta{AExp} &
\str{strict} &
i_1\kbin{/}i_2 \to i_1 \sop{/\!}{Int} i_2 \qquad \text{when $i_2\ne0$} \\
\meta{BExp}
& \Ceq & \meta{AExp}\krel{<=}\meta{AExp} &
\str{seqstrict} &
i_1\krel{<=}i_2 \to i_1 \sop{\le}{Int} i_2 \\
& \mid & \kop{not}\meta{BExp} &
\str{strict} &
\kop{not} t \to \sop{\lnot}{Bool} t \\
& \mid & \meta{BExp}\krel{and}\meta{BExp} &
\str{strict\textup{(1)}} &
\dbl{
  \meta{true}\krel{and} b \to b \\
  \meta{false}\krel{and} b \to \kword{false}
} \\
\meta{Stmt}
& \Ceq & \kword{skip}\kpun{;} &
&
\kword{skip}\kpun{;} \to {\cdot} \\
& \mid & \meta{Id}\krel{=}\meta{AExp}\kpun{;} &
\str{strict\textup{(2)}} &
\sem{\subexp{x\krel{=}i\kpun{;}}{\cdot}\quad \sv}{k}
  \quad \sem{\sv\quad x\mapsto \subexp{{\!\underline{\quad }\!}}{\,i\,}\quad \sv}{state} \\
& \mid & \meta{Stmt}\quad \meta{Stmt} &
&
s_1\quad s_2 \rightharpoonup s_1 \curvearrowright s_2 \\
& \mid & \krel{if}\meta{BExp}\;\dbl{\krel{then}\meta{Stmt}\\\krel{else}\meta{Stmt}} &
\str{strict\textup{(1)}} &
  \dbl{
    \krel{if}\meta{true}\krel{then} s \krel{else} \_ \to s \\
    \krel{if}\meta{false}\krel{then} \_ \krel{else} s \to s
  } \\
& \mid & \krel{while}\meta{BExp}\krel{then}\meta{Stmt} &
&
\sem{
  \dsubexp
    {\krel{while} b \krel{do} s}
    {\krel{if} b \krel{then} (s\krel{while} b \krel{do} s)
     \krel{else}\kword{skip}\kpun{;}}
  \quad \sv}{k} \\
\meta{Pgm}
& \Ceq & \kop{var}\mathsf{List}[\meta{Id}]\kpun{;}\quad \meta{Stmt} &
&
\sem{\dsubexp{\kop{var}xl\kpun{;}\quad s}{s}}{k}
  \quad \sem{\dsubexp{\cdot}{xl\mapsto 0}}{state} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]